# mediaelement.js youtube video player not showing controls in Internet explorer

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am creating a html5 video tag youtube video player using attached mediaelement.js library. Please note this is not the latest available version of the library as client wants the implementation to be done based on this version only.

The issue is the controls like progress bar and duration are not coming in IE however they are displayed correctly on google chrome. Inspecting the DOM after rendering I found that content under the layers is not getting created in IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="mediaelement_and_player.js"></script>
 <link href="mediaelementplayer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#youtube_video').mediaelementplayer(); 
 });
 </script>
 <video id="youtube_video" width="400" height="300" controls="controls" preload="none">
        <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNf7KbqPGSM" type="video/youtube">
    </video> 
  </body>
</html>
```

[Here is  the complete jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/AS1757/qj97schb/) Please help ..

Comment: Which version are you using? Have you tried it with the most recent version? If that works you might need to backport the bugfixes.

Comment: Hi I am using version 2.23.1. No, I haven't tried the latest version as I can not use it and also the controls are visible on Internet explorer with the same version on live site https://www.ubykotex.com/en-us/?returnurl=kotex.com but I am unable to figure out why its not working for me.

Comment: This is resolved after hosting the project on a server.